# raise ValueError("Explorer API not set for this network") ValueError: Explorer API not set for this network

Tags: etherscan, python, rinkeby, brownie, network

I run this code in brownie:
brownie run scripts/deploy.py --networks Rinkeby

```
deploy.py:

from brownie import network, config, accounts
from brownie import FundMe

def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy({"from": account},publish_source=True)
    print(f"contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def get_account():
    if network.show_active() == "development":
        return accounts[0]
    else:
        return accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])



def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

..............................................................................
FundMe.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6 ;

import "smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
//.......................................................................................................

contract FundMe {
   using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xa7e39728bFF3b2da35F90E95c108Fcf2cb021D72);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xa7e39728bFF3b2da35F90E95c108Fcf2cb021D72);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
         return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
    }

    // 1000000000
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

        for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
}

//..............................................................................................
```

......................

Comment: It like this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/152261/brownie-explorer-api-not-set-for-this-network

Answer (score 1):

It is not something related to your contract code, otherwise, it would not compile.

If your brownie-config.yaml setting names did not match you would get an error. then only thing it might be is `publish_source=True`

Remove `publish_source=True`. try without publishing. if you are on a development network, etherscan will not know about your development network

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. Any suggestions on help? My brownie-config.yaml file seems ok:

networks:
default: development
rinkeby:
eth_usd_price_feed: '0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e'
verify: True
mainnet-fork-dev:
eth_usd_price_feed: '0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419'
verify: True
development:
verify: False
ganache-local:
verify: False

Comment: Figured it out. In my brownie-config.yaml i needed to set verify to false for the mainnet-fork-dev

Answer (score 0):

you need to set publish_source = False if on a mock network so that it does not try verify an API that does not really exist.

see this video 5h25! (its a long video)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the network flag when running your script.

Something like

```
Brownie run main.py --network YOUR_NETWORK_HERE
```