# Brownie Explorer API not set for this network

Tags: etherscan, brownie

I am trying to deploy a solidity contract with the source code to a Sepolia test net, using Brownie. The contract deploys successfully, but the source code does not. I keep getting this error.

```bash
  File "C:\Users\drew_\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\drew_\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 15, in main
    deploy_fund_me()
  File ".\scripts\deploy.py", line 7, in deploy_fund_me
    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
  File "C:\Users\drew_\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 549, in __call__
    return tx["from"].deploy(
  File "C:\Users\drew_\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\account.py", line 557, in deploy
    contract.publish_source(deployed_contract, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\drew_\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 338, in publish_source
    raise ValueError("Explorer API not set for this network")
ValueError: Explorer API not set for this network
```

I have set the `export ETHERSCAN_TOKEN` inside my `.env` file and I have added my `.env` to the `brownie-config`

Here is my `brownie-config`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink@2.2.0 
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.9.2
compiler:
  solc: 
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink@2.2.0"
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.9.2"
dotenv: .env
wallets:
    from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
networks:
  sepolia: 
    explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/
    verify: True

live:
- name: Ethereum
  networks:
  - name: sepolia
    chainid: 11155111
    id: sepolia
    host: https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{myKey}
    explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only you have to add the sepolia network to the brownie-config.yaml

Also you must add the sepolia network to the networks with the explorer included, i.e. via cmd line:

brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host="https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/{your id}" chainid=11155111 explorer=https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api

Also, make sure you have the ETHERSCAN token correctly added on your .env file

hope it works. It worked on mine.